# FBGraph api dont want to access friendslist

Tags: ios, objective-c, fb-graph

recently I have used the **FBGraph** api . In that I have used this method

```
 [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,publish_stream" andSuperView:self.view];
```

to get the photos from my account . At the very first time it is asking me that iOS app would like to access photos,friendslist. But I don't want to use the friendlist . So could any one tell me how to remove the friendslist (It should show iOS app would like to access photos). According to the Facebook docs by default it gives the friendslist permission , but we dont want it .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `publish_stream` from your extended permissions.

Answer (score 0):

use this permissions :  @"publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins,read_stream,email"